# MUnit mocks: Which Attribute failed verification?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mule

I'm busy writing MUnit test cases for a subflow. I've mocked out a component to prevent emails being sent, but mainly to confirm that my flow is passing the correct attributes to that SMTP component.

I can use a verifier to confirm that whether the call matched an expected configuration. But if it doesn't match, how does one verify exactly which attribute was missing? 
Is it best practise to individually verify on each Attribute rather than all of them together? Or what is the process?

If I do that I can get a line number of which verification failed.

Is there no way to give a "message" to print when MUnit tests/verifications fail? JUnit does this and it's extremely helpful when viewing test results and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a message when the verification fail:

You can use Spy MP if you want to run a set of assertions before the MP you are mocking

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/wiki/spy-message-processors

if The assertion is complex you can write it in JAVA

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/wiki/assertions#custom-assertions

Comment: "You can provide a message..."  Really? How? Please show me a Java code example. When a verifier fails, it gives no information as to what check failed, for that reason a custom message would help, but even that isn't possible yet